# mysql stored function does not work with prepared statements (php)

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, innodb

I'm trying to create a sequence replacement in innoDB (since auto_increment behaves differently than in myisam). So i've created a stored function, named **seq**. I can use it as follows:

```
INSERT INTO a_table(id) VALUES(seq('seq_a_table'));
```

My mysqli based database library automatically uses prepared statements, so i get this error:

```
This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet
```

MySQL version: 5.1.48 (OSX snow leopard).

**UPDATE**

Wow, i feel stupid... i was so confused by the error that i missed the simple fact that it wasn't thrown by the statement in question. I was using transactions and forgot that my query function automatically compiles everything as statements, including "START TRANSACTION".
So for future late night coders - do not try to start a transaction in a statement :)

Comment: _What the hell is the piont of having them?_ They work in most common cases, isn't that a good thing?

Comment: Could you show how you're trying to use the prepared statement?

Comment: @Barmar spoken like a true optimist :) I'm simply tired of trying to overcome a problem only to face another with this stupid db engine. I've updated my answer to show you how my lib works, but you probably won't find anything exciting there.

Comment: What's the value of `$q`? I wanted to see how you're trying to call the stored procedure with the parametrized query.

Comment: It's not optimism, just a statement of fact: Most SQL applications can take advantage of prepared statements. There are a number of situations where they can't be used, and this is one of them.

Comment: @Barmar value of $q is the query in my original question in this case. It is static so no bindings are performed in this case on it. But this is JUST AN EXAMPLE CASE.

Comment: If you're not doing any bindings, there's no difference between a regular query and a prepared query.

Comment: @Barmar ... THIS PARTICULAR EXAMPLE does not use any bindings (as it has already been mentioned like 17 times). Does that mean my real world situations won't use bindings? Certainly not! If i didn't need bindings, i would've used mysqli_query instead

Comment: OK. I originally asked for the code because I assumed mysql's issue was with performing substitution of bindings in certain cases. But I guess it rejects the preparation if it contains certain constructs. Can you use a stored procedure instead of a user-defined function? I've seen examples of the latter with prepared statements, so they should work.

Comment: @Barmar i don't think i can do that. I basically need it to return a value and be able to simply insert it into a query. I don't think stored procedures can do it as simple as shown in my example.

Answer (score -1):

why not just use the old mysql for that case. something like:

```
$con = mysql_connect("192.168.x.x","host","pass");
if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("yourdb", $con) or die("cannot select DB");

mysql_query( "INSERT INTO a_table(id) VALUES(seq('seq_a_table'))" );
```

Comment: Because it is deprecated

Comment: *"why not just use the old mysql for that case."* - Um... no. The use of `MySQL_` is deprecated. Therefore using `MySQLi_` at the very least, is the way to go.

Comment: @user4035 Beat me to it by 4 seconds ;-)

Comment: @AwokeKnowing - Don't be surprised if you get downvoted. Won't be me, but don't be surprised.

Comment: Why not? Why don't we use it in the first place? Because my query is just an example and in real life you want to be protected from injections as well as possible. And using your suggestion would require escaping strings which is the reason i moved to prepared statements in the first place.

Comment: You can't mix mysql and mysqli in the same program. You can use mysqli without prepared statements, and the OP probably knows that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- why should it get hacked? Don't you consider prepared statements safer than string escaping?

Comment: @Marius Please answer Barmars question about the value of $q

Comment: Value of $q is the query i supplied in the question. It is a static query so no escaping is done and no bindings are done in this case as well

Comment: @Fred-ii- i am using MySQLi, you must be confusing something  :)

Comment: @Marius Major groan... my apologies, you are right. I was confusing the conversation with what `AwokeKnowing` posted as an answer. Again, my apologies. I deleted previous comments.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no worries :) As you can see though, switching ended up giving me headaches at the end anyway :)

Comment: guys, I'm really sorry for just posting a possible solution in a passive way without saying this is the way to do it.  There are better ways, for sure.  My point was just that you could use basic sql, at a minimum.

Comment: @Marius Can you explain, please, what is sequence replacement and what do you do in seq function. You are trying to do something tricky, and mysqli doesn't support it?

Comment: @Marius Well, it's better to deal with it now, then later which is good in a way. `MySQL_` would have eventually stopped running in future releases.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing it's ok - your solution is the only one that would work in this case :)

Comment: @Marius Did you try `mysqli_query`?

Comment: @user4035 i'm trying to add an auto increment field in innoDB, but it works differently than in myisam (as stated in original post). So my seq() function returns a new sequence value that does not reset in the case of server shutdown.

Comment: @user4035 i could, but my query will not be as trivial as in original post and i don't want to expose it to security issues. And yes, i do know about escaping, but i don't think it's as safe as prepared statements.

Comment: prepared statements are just php doing some checking for you. if you do the checking yourself, then you can just use basic sql and get the job done.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing with prepared statements the arguments are not inserted into the query directly, eliminating the need for sanitizing them. It's a very different thing and php does not do the checking for you, since there is no need for it so to speak.